# Salesorderdetail detail not bring amount from product, CRM 2015

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have created a plugin in which I am creating Sales Order and then creating salesorderdetail (sales order products) dynamically. Everything is working fine, products are shown correctly in the sub grid on order form but there is no price on the products at all.

I am using the following code to create sales order product.  When I create a quote then quote the product using same code (changing entity and references to quote) then later converting that quote to an order everything is fine.  However when I create an order and order product directly it is not working.

Please suggest a solution.

```
var orderProduct = new Entity
{
    LogicalName = "salesorderdetail"
};

orderProduct.Attributes.Add("salesorderid", new EntityReference("salesorder", OrderId));
orderProduct.Attributes.Add("productid", new EntityReference(product.LogicalName, product.Id));
orderProduct.Attributes.Add("quantity", Convert.ToDecimal(1));
orderProduct.Attributes.Add("uomid", new EntityReference("uom", uom.Id));

_service.Create(orderProduct);
```

Comment: Could you please expound upon, " not working". Error etc ...

Comment: There is no error at all. Order Products are being created fine in the CRM and i can see those product on the Order form in sub grid, but total amount on the order is 0.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this.
When creating Order Products (salesorderdetail) using Plugin or webserivce and prices on the products should be coming from CRM automatically then
ispriceoverridden and isproductoverriden should be set to false explicitly in the code.
Working for me now :)